# Virtual list is empty using Framework 7 in intel xdk

Tags: intel-xdk, html-framework-7

I am using a virtual list everything works fine if I initialize and render it using onclick button event. However, I need this list to be initialized and rendered on creating a certain page, when I do so the list items are empty.

```
   var myList = myApp.virtualList('.list-block.virtual-list', {
   items: 
    [
    {
        title: 'Item 1',
        picture: 'path/to/picture1.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Item 2',
        picture: 'path/to/picture2.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Item 1000',
        picture: 'path/to/picture1000.jpg'
    },
    ],
    template: '<li class="item-content">' +
                  '<div class="item-media"><img src="{{picture}}"></div>' +
                  '<div class="item-inner">' +
                  '<div class="item-title">{{title}}</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
              '</li>'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem with Intel XDK and virtual list of Framework 7.

After a quick debugging I realize that it needs an option, the rowsAfter, to load the elements. Without that it calculate two index, like skip and limit in pagination, that are both zero.

I have about 2300 array elements so I set rowsAfter to 40, but if you have just 3 elements you can try with 3 (so it should show element 0, 1 and 2), like this:

```
   var myList = myApp.virtualList('.list-block.virtual-list', {
   items: 
    [
    {
        title: 'Item 1',
        picture: 'path/to/picture1.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Item 2',
        picture: 'path/to/picture2.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Item 1000',
        picture: 'path/to/picture1000.jpg'
    },
    ],
    rowsAfter : 3,
    template: '<li class="item-content">' +
                  '<div class="item-media"><img src="{{picture}}"></div>' +
                  '<div class="item-inner">' +
                  '<div class="item-title">{{title}}</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
              '</li>'
    });
```